# How to check what value is being returned by gets() function in C?

Tags: c, gets

I'm trying to print what the gets() fuctions returns in C.

I tried various format specifiers but none seemed to help.

```
char a[100];
char (*p)[100];
p=gets(a);
printf("%s",p);
```

it just says segmentation fault.

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. It was [removed from the Standard in 2011](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp6) and [declared obsolescent in C99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.26.9)

Comment: I understand it has been deprecated but while working on a project I stumbled upon this question, like what does it return.
The documentation says it returns the pointer to the a but I'm unable to access a using what it returns.

Comment: After the edit: the types of `a` (or the returned value from `gets()`) and `p` are not compatible. Turn on your compiler warnings and mind them.

Comment: Although there is next to nothing **right** about this excerpt, this code should not produce a segmentation fault in common implementations **except** if by overwriting the buffer `gets` is reading to, or if it returns NULL. Which gets us back to the point 1: **never use `gets`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`gets()` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.7.7)

> The gets function returns [the original argument] if successful. If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, [...] a null pointer is returned. If a read error occurs during the operation, [...] a null pointer is returned.

So, the `gets()` function (with C99 or earlier) returns its argument or `NULL`.

Note that it was [marked obsolescent in C99 (2007 TC)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.26.9) and [removed from the Standard in C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp6).

---

```
char a[100];
char *p;
p = gets(a); // assign a (&a[0]) to p if no errors
printf("%c is the same as %c\n", a[0], p[0]);
```

Comment: You should check `p` isn't null before doing `p[0]`

Comment: chuckling... the was to leave open the option to reproduce the segmentation fault -- for purely educational purposes `:)`

Comment: Actually, `gets()` wasn't marked obsolescent until 2007 in the relevant TC.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, info integrated into my answer